# angularjs: I need reset form without showing required fields with red color

Tags: angularjs

when save my form (user) 
after that I need to reset it to save new user
If I reset just like that 
user = {};
and try to save new  user
all the mandatory fields are appear with red color

how can I reset my form to avoid the red color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can reset it like below:

```
$scope.resetForm =  function() {
    $scope.user= {};
    $scope.formName.$setPristine();
    $scope.formName.$setValidity();
    $scope.formName.$setUntouched();
}
```

call this function from your save function success...

Answer (score 0):

You can make function and pass whatever form you want to reset:

```
$scope.resetForm = function(formName){
   formName.$setPristine();
};
```